# Split and alter values of pandas 'groupby' elements based on length of the groups

Tags: python, pandas, etl, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a pandas DataFrame object with a column named *'order_id'*. Rows with the same id belong to one and the same order (size can be anything between 1 and 1000), e.g.:

```
sales_orders = {
    'order_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    # multiple other fields 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(sales_orders)
```

I need to split the groups into smaller chunks based on a cut-off value like for instance 3. Ideally, nothing else changes other than the suffix of the column, i.e.:

```
'order_id': [1-0, 1-0, 1-0, 1-1, 1-1, 1-1, 1-2, 2, 2, 2, 3-0, 3-0, 3-0, 3-1, 3-1, 3-1, 3-2, 3-2, 3-2, 4]
```

I assume that one can simply step through the groups and touch each group individually in a for loop like this:

```
for order_id, group in df.groupby(by=['order_id']):
    if group.shape[0] > 2:
        # change column line by line
```

But this looks incredibly unpanda'ish and horrifically slow. Thus I would appreciate a sensible, performant and readable solution ;)
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumcount` to get the suffixes, then use `np.where` to conditionally set them.

```
c = df.groupby('order_id').cumcount() // 3
m = (c == 0).groupby(df.order_id).transform('all')

df['order_id2'] = (
    np.where(m, df.order_id, df.order_id.astype(str) + '-' + c.astype(str))
      .astype(str))

df.head(10)

   order_id order_id2
0         1       1-0
1         1       1-0
2         1       1-0
3         1       1-1
4         1       1-1
5         1       1-1
6         1       1-2
7         2         2
8         2         2
9         2         2
```

---

A slightly simpler solution if you are fine with 2 and 4 also having suffixes; you can use `groupby` and `cumcount` to generate the suffixes, then use `str.cat` to join them.

```
c = (df.groupby('order_id').cumcount() // 3).astype(str)
df['order_id3'] = df['order_id'].astype(str).str.cat(c, sep='-')

df.head(10)

   order_id order_id2 order_id3
0         1       1-0       1-0
1         1       1-0       1-0
2         1       1-0       1-0
3         1       1-1       1-1
4         1       1-1       1-1
5         1       1-1       1-1
6         1       1-2       1-2
7         2         2       2-0
8         2         2       2-0
9         2         2       2-0
```

Comment: Runs like a charm, you sir are awesome!